# $f(x) = \det(E+Ax)$; find a derivative of this function in $x_0 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, determinant, trace

How do I prove that $f'(x_0) =\text{tr}(A)$  where $x_0 = 0$ and $f(x) = \det(E+Ax)$ for some square matrix $A$?

P.S. I'm pretty sure there exists a solution that doesn't use anything more complicated than definitions of the determinant, trace and derivative. I'm just starting to learn linear algebra and I'm only familiar with basic things.

Comment: What are the domain and range of $f$?  It looks like $f$ takes points in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ and returns scalars in $\mathbf{R}$, so its gradient is a vector field.  Yet, $tr(A)$ is a scalar, while the gradient of $f$ is a vector field.

Comment: $f$ takes a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$ and returns a scalar in the same $\mathbb{R}$. It just multiplies some unknown matrix $A$ by the given $x$, which is a scalar, adds $E$ to the result and calculates the trace of the resulting matrix (and yes, it took me a while to understand how does this even work)

Comment: Ah, OK, that works.

Comment: Note that $x^nf(-\frac1x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which has the trace in a prominent place

Comment: @Akiiino Wikipedia's "Determinant" page has some good formulas that express determinant in terms of trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the derivative of $\det(I+tA)$ at $t=0$, we want to write
$$ \det(I+tA) = \det(I) + ct + o(t) $$
for some $c$, which will be the derivative.

If we expand $\det(I+tA)$ by the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants), we find that almost all of the terms contain at least two factors of $t$ and so belong in the $o(t)$ part. The only one this *isn't* the case for is the product of the diagonal elements:
$$ \det(I+tA) = (1+ta_{11})(1+ta_{22})\cdots(1+ta_{nn}) + \text{terms involving }t^2 $$

Expanding this product with the distributive law we get
$$ \det(I+tA) = 1 + (ta_{11}+ta_{22}+\cdots+ta_{nn}) + \text{terms involving }t^2 + \text{more such terms} $$

The terms of degree 1 are exactly $t$ times the trace of $A$, so this trace must be the derivative we're looking for.

---

If you're not familiar with little-$o$ notation, you can also work with the high-school definition of derivative; we get
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1+(ta_{11}+\cdots+ta_{nn})+(\text{terms involving }t^2) - 1}{t-0} = a_{11}+\cdots+a_{nn}$$

Answer (score 2):

I work in the field $C$, let $P$ be a matrix such that $PAP^{-1}$ is sup triangular, $c_1,...c_n$ the eigenvalues of $A$, $det(E+xA)=det(P(E+xA)P^{-1})=det(E+xPAP^{-1})=(1+xc_1)...(1+xc_n)$, this implies that $det(E+xA)=1+x(c_1+...+c_n)+x^2U(x)$ and henceforth ${d\over{dx}}_{x=0}=c_1+...+c_n=tr(A)$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a simpler solution (honestly, I hardly understand half of what's written in here, and I'm supposed to be able to solve this task). Still, if nothing else will emerge, I'll accept your answer