# Why does the Wronskian work?

Tags: linear-algebra, wronskian

I'm looking at this: [https://math.berkeley.edu/~mcivor/math54s11/wronskian.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emcivor/math54s11/wronskian.pdf). Which says this: "The fact that the Wronskian is nonzero at $x_0$ means that the square matrix on the left is nonsingular, hence this equation has only the solution $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, so $f$ and $g$ are independent."
Where the "square matrix on the left" is the Wronskian and $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions. I understand how this proves a solution, but I don't understand how this shows that the only solution is $c_1 = c_2 = 0$. Why can't it be any solution as long as $Wc = 0$?

Comment: When a matrix $A$ is nonsingular (invertible), the only solution of $A\vec x=\vec 0$ is $\vec x=\vec 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh. I did not know that. Thanks!! On further inspection that should have been obvious.

Comment: Note that in $Wc=0$, $c$ is a constant (doesn't depend on $x$) and $W=W(x)$ is a function of $x$.  So solving for the one point $x=x_0$ fix the value of $c$ for all $x$.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3823089/121671), through a little advanced for your needs, has a detail connection between wronskian and differential equations.